# Releasing stable version from development versions with GitFlow

Tags: git, git-flow

So currently we're working a team and sort of use GitFlow as our version control workflow in Git. We work in iterations where we do a production deployment every week, containing all tickets that are tested by QA and accepted by the product owner. This means that we have maybe deployed 20 tickets to test, 15 tickets passed QA and will be added to the release. The 5 tickets that are sent back to the developer, may not be included to the release.

In our version control we have the following branches:

- **feature/*** - The developer(s) working on a specific ticket, will commit their and push their changes until they finished the work done for the ticket. This branch is created based on the develop-branch and regularly pulls in changes from develop to keep up with other devs.
- **develop** - To this branch the developer merges the changes done in the feature-branch. Also our CI-environment listens to this branch to build and deploy the latest development version to the test-environment.
- **release/x.x** - This branch is used to prepare a new release to deliver to the product owner/UAT. Here is our problem. Because we can't release all of the tickets to production, we can't just merge everything from develop to this branch. So at the moment we're manually cherry-picking all stuff, which is really horrible since everything gets organized and comes with a lot of conflicts. Also merging everything from develop, but reverting the tickets that can't go live doesn't seem like a sustainable solution.
- **master** - Stable version of the application.

My initial idea was to create feature-branches based on the master-branch, but that would mean developers are always developing on an older version of the application. This again could lead to integration issues later in the process.

I imagine that i'm not the only one with this problem. What is your experience with this issue?

Comment: Cherry picking from develop into release sounds atrocious to me.  You should either merge the whole branch or not merge it at all.

Comment: Hi @Thom we have the same scenario except that our releases are not so regular.  We only ported over to git a few months ago, so are still learning how to adopt git-flow to our environment.  I'll be interested to read the answers to your question.  It doesn't really answer your question, but so far we have been developing feature branches on `develop` and then cutting a `release/x.x` from `develop` at the point we are ready for UAT.  Any small new features or fixes created during UAT  are branched from/to the 'release/x.x' branch.  Rejected features will need a manual undo of the merge commit.

Comment: Hi @Rob, Thanks! It seems like a decent way to manage releases in Git. We also have fully changed to Git since a few months. So within the whole organization we don't have that much experience process wise. I'm hoping to find a way that we just can fully merge features separately to the release it should go into.

Comment: So, finally how did you manage to handle this problem ? I'm interested to.

Answer (score 2):

I really like the git workflow described in this article: "http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/"

This is how they recommend creating/merging feature branches:

> *Creating a feature branch*
>
> When starting work on a new feature, branch off from the develop
>   branch.
>
> `$  git checkout -b myfeature develop`
>
> Switched to a new branch "myfeature"
>
> *Incorporating a finished feature on develop*
>
> Finished features may be merged into the develop branch to definitely add them
>   to the upcoming release:
>
> `$ git checkout develop`
>
> Switched to branch 'develop'
>
> `$ git merge --no-ff myfeature`
>
> Updating ea1b82a..05e9557 (Summary of changes)
>
> `$ git branch -d myfeature`
>
> Deleted branch myfeature (was 05e9557).
>
> `$ git push origin develop`
>
> The --no-ff flag causes the merge to always create a
>   new commit object, even if the merge could be performed with a
>   fast-forward. This avoids losing information about the historical
>   existence of a feature branch and groups together all commits that
>   together added the feature.

Comment: Whilst this answer is generally informative, I don't think it answers the original question, especially with how to deal with the fact that some features may not make it successfully through UAT.

Comment: Thank you for point this out. Although it is a very interesting, this indeed doesn't completely solve my problem. Since this workflow assumes that the release is a full snapshot of the current development version, while that isn't the case for us. We always need to be able to release separate features, preferably with the least manual work possible.